# Why are there generic ship class cards in Star Trek Attack Wing?

Tags: miniatures, star-trek-attack-wing

The base game of Star Trek Attack Wing consists of three ships, one for the main factions.

Every ship has one ship card that marks it as a capital ship, for the Federation it naturally is the Enterprise.

Additionally, there is a generic ship card that marks the ship only as "Galaxy Class":

[image]

The generic ship is of course a little bit weaker than the capital ship. Why is this second card even there? Under what circumstances would I play with a weaker "Galaxy Class Starship" instead of the stronger "U.S.S. Enterprise"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See that yellow starburst to the left of "U.S.S. Enterprise-D"? See also that there's *no* yellow starburst to the left of "Federation Starship"?

[image]

That starburst is the "Unique Icon" which denotes that the card is unique, which means you can only have one copy of it in play at any given time.

Being a Unique ship, you just *can't* have multiple U.S.S. Enterprise-Ds running around at once, no matter how awesome ([and canonical](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode)#Act_Five)) you might think that'd be. The Federation Starship, on the other hand, is *not* Unique: This means you *can* make a whole fleet of Galaxy-class starships if you wanted to (within your squadron point limit, of course), regardless of whether or not the U.S.S. Enterprise-D is already there.

Other than that, I guess maybe you might want to save two points and bring in the cheaper 26-cost Federation Starship instead splurging on the better 28-cost one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This raises the question how I distinguish multiple identical ships on the board, but I guess I'll ask a separate question to that when the need for it arises.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for the artful labeling :D

Comment: Use tokens (two green tokens and two red tokens for example, put one of each tokens to the ship and the other on the card) or rubber bands (can be wrapped around the base or flight stand of the ship and the card could be put halfly covering the second rubber band) for quick or paint the base or flight stand and sleeve the card for longtime use.